# Finding Child of Parent Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am have a link in a li and when you click on it, it should open a ul, also contained in the li.  I can't seem to get it to select the right element though. Code below

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">hi</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="hidden">more stuff</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.hidden{display:none;}
```

Js

```
$( "a" ).click(function() {
     $(this).parent("li").children("ul").css("display","block");
});
```

Comment: [`$(this).next('ul').children('li').removeClass('hidden');`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/eyfsL6L8/). [Use toggleClass to toggle](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/eyfsL6L8/1/).

Comment: The problem here is you are setting the `ul` element to `display: block` (*which was already like that*), the `<li>` inside is still hidden.

Comment: Don't use inline styles when you can add/remove `hidden` class

Answer (score 1):

Since the `ul` is the *next sibling* to the `a`, you'd use [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next) to access it. Then you can look at the `ul`'s children ([`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children)) or descendants ([`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find)) for the `.hidden` one and remove the class ([`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass)):

```
$(this).next().children(".hidden").removeClass("hidden");
```

**Live Example:**

```js
$("a").on("click", function() {
  $(this).next().children(".hidden").removeClass("hidden");

  return false;
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">one</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="hidden">more stuff</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">two</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="hidden">more stuff</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">three</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="hidden">more stuff</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are trying to make `ul` displayed although it is visible and it does not effect the `li` under it so you need to access that `li` like this. Removing the `hidden` class of the element to make it displayed is a better approach than assigning inline style as the commentators said

```
$(this).parent("li").children("ul").children("li").removeClass("hidden");
```

Comment: Don't use inline styles.

Comment: @Tushar It's the original approach of the OP. This is explaining why their above code doesn't work and explains how to fix that. But yes, it basically removes the point of the class.

Comment: Use `removeClass('hidden')` instead of `css('..`

Answer (score 0):

check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/67L6zn5c/) fiddler link...

hope it will help you....

```
$( "a" ).click(function() {
    $(this).next().children(".hidden").removeClass("hidden");
});
```